# How to get css variables from root?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, devexpress

In my react project, I have defined color variables, and for the devextreme pie chart ui component, i want to define my own color palette.

```css
:root {
--my-pastel: var(--rose) var(--beige) var(--bright-orange) var(--brighter-orange) var(--bright-rose) var(--bright-red);
}
```

in my fn i need to register the palette:

```js
import { registerPalette } from "devextreme/viz/palette";

const MyPastel = ?

registerPalette("My Pastel", MyPastel);
```

in my componenet

```js
 <PieChart
            
                dataSource={dataSource}
                palette="MyPastel"
            
            >
                <Series
                    argumentField="category"
                    valueField="value"
                >
                    <Label visible={true} />
                </Series>
                <Legend visible={true} />
            </PieChart>
```

How can I achieve this?

I have tried computedStyle and other maping methids but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

CSS

```
:root {
    --blue: #007bff;
    --indigo: #6610f2;
    --purple: #6f42c1;
    --pink: #e83e8c;
    --red: #dc3545;
}
```

JS

```
import { registerPalette } from "devextreme/viz/palette";

const getCssVaribleValue = (variableName) => 
    getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue(variableName);

const palleteColors = [
    getCssVaribleValue('--blue'),
    getCssVaribleValue('--indigo'),
    getCssVaribleValue('--purple'),
    getCssVaribleValue('--pink'),
    getCssVaribleValue('--red'),
];

const pallete = { simpleSet: palleteColors };
registerPalette("My Pastel", pallete);
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip. But sadly this solution does not work for me.